# Is it possible use HashMultimap to create spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, multimap

XML:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap">
  <constructor-arg index="0" value="200"/>
  <constructor-arg index="1" value="2"/>
</bean>
```

Is it correct? When I try to inject this bean in another like:

```
<property name="myBean" ref="myBean"/>
```

i received the error: Cannot apply property values to null instance

Comment: Mind to show us the error?

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: As long as object type is same it should work.

Comment: Show us the declaration of bean where you are injecting the property.

Comment: Cannot apply property values to null instance

Comment: @user710818 Ok, you'll need to show more context. Post your whole context file or at least the bean that tries to reference the map.

Comment: You've fallen in an extreme case. This exception is rarely thrown. Please show your context and bean declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<bean id="myBean" factory-method="create" class="com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="200" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="2" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This won't be a problem for Spring. It can use reflection to access the private constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMultimap` does not have a public constructor, therefore it's neither a Bean nor a POJO.

Source: [google collections - HashMultimap](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.java?r=80)

Instances are created using the static factory methods, among them one with no arguments (`create()`), maybe you can use this?

Comment: I would like use one with arguments

Comment: @user710818 Why can't you show us the error message? Else we all can only guess the issue.

Comment: Cannot apply property values to null instance

Comment: Spring doesn't need the public constructor. It can use the private constructor just fine with reflection.

Comment: If constructors are private, that' usually for a good reason which should be respected (e.g. no constructor access for utility classes, controlled access for singleton classes). Depending on white box information is bad programming style, doesn't matter if this is supported or encouraged by any framework.

Comment: @PeterWalser If you want to give advice, please use a comment or post on Spring's board. This answer is not useful to the OP.